# ドットが複数入っているファイル名は一般的なものですか？

Tags: filesystems, 命名規則

githubなどでソースを読むにあたり、foo.class.phpやfuga.min.cssなど、ファイル名にドットが複数入っているものを時々目にしますが、この書き方は一般的な書き方なのでしょうか？この書き方によるメリット・または危険性があれば教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 4):

一般的かと思います。
歴史的には、1990年代には、UNIXのファイルシステムは、ファイル名に複数のドットが含まれているのをサポートしていましたし、その派生(?)であるLinuxのファイルシステムも同様でした。WindowsでもFAT32ファイルシステムでサポートしていたと記憶してます。(1998年くらいから)

＃HDFSはよくわかりませんが、現在はサポートしてます。

使い方は人それぞれと思いますが、名称の単語間を区切る文字として利用するのをよく見かけます。(質問の例だと「foo」「class」を区切っている)

特別メリットがあるわけではないですが、Windows、MacOS、Linuxのどこでも利用できるので、ファイル名中の単語の区切りとしては都合がよいと思います。
危険性も特にないと思います。

Comment: 丁寧な解説ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

`.`も英数字と同じくファイル名を構成する記号のひとつに過ぎないので、「複数含めてはいけない」というルールは特にありません。

質問文での例に挙げられたものと考え方は少し違いますが、Linuxでは`.tar.gz`のような二重拡張子も一般的に使われています。

ファイル名の末尾にいわゆる拡張子として`*.txt`の形式で名前付けを行うのは元々「ファイルの種類を判別しやすいように」というだけで、プログラムの関連付けまで意味を持たせているのはWindowsのみです。

Comment: 一般的な使い方なのですね。ありがとうございます